# multiple onclick event only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have multiple onclick events:

It works the first time but if I try it again it does not work...
How do I fix this? I have no idea, the solutions I have noticed about some DOM cascade or some such is really... I have the definition for the 
play and delay functions here, for use, although I think they are irrelevant 
in regards the problem, which is contextual. Please help?

```
function delay (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 2500 );
}

function play(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
}
```

I've heard that its called "obtrusive javascript" however I myself am too obtuse myself to be unobtrusive.....

Comment: <div class="alphabet brighten" onclick="onclick=play();delay('alphabet.html')" > </div>  - this is where its called. Of course I use the delay to allow the short sound clip to finish playing before it goes to the next page...

Comment: What are you expecting the next time you click, the audio is already playing ?

Comment: If your using the same functions for multiple elements, **ID's must be unique** ?

Comment: I am using classes not ID's... I'm a bit confused though because when I use the back button to that page, the multiple onclick function no longer works at all... Its when I return to that page, and then it won't work again, remember its a link. But if I use the back button and return to the page it simply doesn't work anymore.

Comment: If you're using classes, how would `getElementById` work ?

Comment: the <div> elements are classes. The functions have ID's.... does that help? I'm a bit of a n00b. Are you saying I should change my divs from classes to unique id's in order for this to work? Is that the problem? I will change my classes to div id's and see if that solves the problem... You are probably right, I do not know.

Comment: I have no idea, I'm just saying that `getElementById` does exactly what the name implies, it gets an element with the **ID** `#audio`, and there can only be ***one*** such element with that given ID.

Comment: but the Element that is gotten (GetElementById), is it the javascript code snippet or is it the div that is the Element being called? I think its the javascript, no? I'm confused...

Comment: No, I changed the div from a class and gave the div a unique ID... still not working... ;) I think the ID refers to the javascript not the html <div>... I will post a solution when I find one...

Comment: SOLVED! haha. Well, no, I have to mention that the problem was that I moved the play() for the sound effect to an invisible wrapper div while the other function in the onclick="function()" was in the div that is "visible".